# How to append lines to csv files with perl

Tags: perl, csv

I have two dozen .csv files, each about a thousand lines long, they've been created with Tie::Array::CSV. Now I want to append a line or two to each of them every day, what's the most efficient way to do that?

I suppose I could read each file into an array, add my data, and write array back to csv again but this means I risk losing all data if something goes wrong during overwrite, and if I create new files I need to figure out some system to automatically manage all those copies of copies that keep piling up every day.

If there's no module to append lines, how to do it manually with all the conventions and escape characters needed for proper csv so that they can be read back into perl without problems?

...

Thanks for replies, I don't have enough reputation to add comments to answers directly so I eidted the original question.

I don't worry about losing my data too much, I can rebuild it from scratch, it would just take time and manual intervention but not enough to warrant running a daily backup system, thought it's always a point to consider. Appending lines should be easier on processing time, too, as writing .csv to disk is relatively slow on my machines.

Opening files in append mode is what I didn't know. WIth solutions involging`$csv->print($fh, $row);` should I be running this through a loop to add more than one line?

I've got another solution proposed on [Perlmonks](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1069865)

```
use Tie::Array::CSV;
my $filename = 'tied.csv';
tie my @file, 'Tie::Array::CSV', $filename;
push(@file,[4,5,6]);
untie @file;
```

Would that work better? I don't have the opportunity to test it right now.

EDIT. Push() solution above worked magic. Consider this closed.

Comment: If you're worried about losing data, invest in backups.

Comment: From `perldoc -f open`, the following text: ` If MODE is >>, the file is opened for appending, again being created if necessary.`

Answer (score 7):

Use [Text::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/Text-CSV-1.32/lib/Text/CSV.pm):

```
use Text::CSV;

my $csv = Text::CSV->new({ binary => 1, auto_diag => 1, eol => "\n"})
        or die "Cannot use CSV: " . Text::CSV->error_diag();

# open in append mode
open my $fh, ">>", "file.csv" or die "Failed to open file: $!";

$csv->print($fh, [ "foo", "bar", "foo,bar" ]);

close $fh;
```

This appends a single line to `file.csv` using `\n` as the EOL character, comma as the field separator (this is the default), and quotes around fields containing commas:

```
foo,bar,"foo,bar"
```